# I am new to coding and stuck on a cipher problem from cs50

Tags: c, encryption, cs50

I am new and still getting the hang of things so help would be much appreciated.
Here is the basic problem:
A key, for example, might be the string NQXPOMAFTRHLZGECYJIUWSKDVB. This 26-character key means that A (the first letter of the alphabet) should be converted into N (the first character of the key), B (the second letter of the alphabet) should be converted into Q (the second character of the key), and so forth.

A message like HELLO, then, would be encrypted as FOLLE, replacing each of the letters according to the mapping determined by the key.

Here is my attempt:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char convert(char c, char *p);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //argv[1] has the key.
    printf("THE KEY:\n%s\n",argv[1]);
    char *ptr;
    ptr=(char*)malloc(50);
    printf("Enter the string to be encoded:\n");
    scanf("%s",ptr);
    printf("%s\n",ptr);
    char ch;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(ptr);i++)
    {
        ch=*ptr;
        ch=convert(ch,&argv[1][0]);
        *ptr=ch;
        ptr++;
    }
    printf("Encoded string is:\n");
    printf("%s",ptr);
    return 0;
}

char convert(char c, char *p)
{
    char x='a';
    char y='A';
    for(int i=0;i<=25;i++)
    {
        if(x==c||y==c)
        {
            return (*p);
        }
        ++x;
        ++y;
        ++p;
    }
}
```

HERE IS THE OUTPUT:

```
 PS C:\Users\Shreyansh\Desktop\CS TUTORIALS\CS50> .\06_Cipher.exe NQXPOMAFTRHLZGECYJIUWSKDVB
THE KEY:
NQXPOMAFTRHLZGECYJIUWSKDVB
Enter the string to be encoded:
HELLO
HELLO
Encoded string is:
LO
```

For some reason the output stops there. Please help. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `scanf("%s",ptr);` = *undefined behavior*. `ptr` points to nothing determinate, much less enough memory for an unbounded string read. Considering that's literally the second function line of this program, it doesn't bode well, for those that follow.

Comment: At the start `scanf("%s",ptr);` but there is no memory allocated to `ptr` and `scanf()` does not do that for you.

Comment: What about now? The output is better but it is still not correct. Thanks for the memory tip. @Weather Vane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems in you code:

0. Activate and read the warning on your compiler, that will help you a lot.
1. no memory is associated to `ptr`

   You should write something like

   ```
   char mem[10];
   char * ptr = mem;
   ```
2. You use `ptr` as a reference and a looping variable

   You modify ptr to read your string, (`ptr++`) but at the end, you write `ptr`: `printf("%s",ptr);` in that case, you don't write what you have converted.
3. Comes from 2. `strlen(ptr)` in the `for` condition is wrong: at first step, it will be ok (`strlen("Hello") == 5`), but after, it becomes wrong: `strlen("ello") !=5`...
4. in `convert` function, ask theses question:

   - what happens if your argument has not the required size?
   - what happens if the character to convert is not a letter?

---

A good way to read string char by char is to use this kind of idiomatic from:

```
int main(){
    char mem[] = "Hello";
    
    // pointer on string to modify it
    char * ptr = mem;

    puts(ptr);


    // first transformation    
    while (*ptr) {
        (*ptr)++;
        ptr++;
    }

    // make ptr points to mem again
    ptr = mem;
    puts(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dude! I got it. It was cuz I moved the pointer and so the it did not point to the start of the converted string. Thanks for pointing it out! Also I see the loop issue. I put the length in an integer and it worked out fine. Thanks for helping me out again :)